# Could not connect Ethernet0 to virtual network --- VMnet0 is missing

Tags: windows-7, vmware-player

VMware Player 5.0.1 build-894247 is installed. In the virtual machine an internet connection is not provided.

Host and guest OSs: Windows 7

Log:

```
VNET: MACVNetPort_Connect: Ethernet0: can't open vmnet device (2)  
2015-05-06T16:54:05.125+02:00| vcpu-0| I120: Msg_Post: Warning  
2015-05-06T16:54:05.125+02:00| vcpu-0| I120: [msg.vnet.connectvnet]  
Could not connect Ethernet0 to virtual network "VMnet8". More  
information can be found in the vmware.log file.  
2015-05-06T16:54:05.125+02:00| vcpu-0| I120:  
[msg.device.startdisconnected] Virtual device Ethernet0 will start disconnected.
```

vnetlib -- uninstall bridge, reboot and installing was done, but it had no effect.

vmnetbridge.dll in %systemroot%\system32 and vmnetbridge.sys in %systemroot%\system32\drivers are existing.

How to resolve this?

EDIT: VMware Player 6 was installed. Now VMnet1 & 8 are existing, but VMnet0 is missing. The virtual network editor doesn't work anymore. Do you have any hint how to add VMnet0?

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue but in **Linux**, and I fixed it by this command in terminal:

```
sudo systemctl start vmware-networks.service
```

Comment: I got `Unit vmware-networks.service not found`

Answer (score 3):

Use "Restore Defaults" in the Virtual Network Editor

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so and how to make the appropriate changes.

Comment: Actually it *doesn’t* answer the question because there is no Virtual Network Editor in **VMPlayer**, only in VMWorkstation.

Comment: The "restore defaults" button does not exist in the linux version of network editor! How do we restore defaults?

Answer (score 1):

In my case VMware is throwing this error when docker was running in the background.
I killed the docker process and restarted VMware and this reestablished the network connection with the VM.

Comment: After quitting docker, I ran `sudo service NetworkManager restart` and `sudo /usr/bin/vmware-networks --start`

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo /usr/bin/vmware-networks --stop
sudo /usr/bin/vmware-networks --start
```

Wait five seconds, retry to connect with Bridge or Nat et voilà! FIXED!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same log messages and my VM had no connectivity.

I solved it by opening VMware workstation (15.5.1) -> Edit -> Virtual Network editor -> Add Network... -> Network name: 8 -> NAT -> Add -> Save

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

First check if your vmware services are running or not.

> `sudo systemctl status vmware-networks.service`

if not then use

> `sudo systemctl start vmware-networks.service`

after that go to Virtual Machine setting and remove the Network Adapter then add a Network Adpater again by going to Add -> Network Adpater with default settings i.e., NAT.

Answer (score -2):

Best solution is either reinstall the VMWare or Repair the VMWare Workstation.

Go to Run 
type appwiz.cpl , hit enter
Go to VMWare Workstation in the programs list.
Right CLick on *VMWare Workstation* , select change
In the upcoming wizard select Repair, follow the steps

After successful repair it will ask you to restart the machine.

When you comeback hopefully everything will work fine. :)

Note : In my case it worked. :)